# What can I use to form concrete countertops longer than 8 feet?

Tags: mold, melamine

Building a concrete counter top 4x10 and cannot fine a sheet of melamine 10 feet long anywhere. Anyone know where I could get a piece? I’d rather not joint to eliminate a seam

Comment: the store down he street has some    ...   no, wait, you don't live here, do you?

Comment: A sheet of ply and sand it smooth or is that 4 metres by 10 metres?

Comment: +1 to a 10' sheet of ply, possibly waxed or varnished for release. (Though melamine can impart an excellent texture on a top...) Failing that, there must be an online supplier that can charge you an arm and a leg to ship a roll of melamine. I think your bigger problem will be finding the football team to move the finished top around.

Comment: If you have a slight seam it will be no big deal I have done a couple of concrete counters and you need to polish the concrete for a good finish the tiny seam is a bump that quickly removed with the first few passes , the difference in polished and not polished is comparable a Olympic swimming pool vs a blow up kiddy pool, just my opinion but you will find anyone that dose these will say similar not only for looks but for sealing the surface also.

Answer (score 2):

Use plywood as your base with a seam, then Formica (plastic laminate) as your base layer in contact with your concrete. You can get Formica cheap because you don't care what it looks like and there is always some pattern that isn't selling and they want to get rid of, you'll make them happy to take it.

Comment: or use metal sheet as a liner